# Why is my process of finding the number of integer years, integer months, and integer days from the number of days not working?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, function

I need to find out the number of integer years, number of integer months, and number of integer days from the number of days, given as an input. However, my process is not working. I am getting the wrong answer.

Note: Assume, each year to be 365 days and each month to be 30 days. Also, please do not consider leap years.

```
user=int(input("Please enter the number of days: "))

def year(num):
  year=int(num/365)
  month=int((num%365)/30)
  day=num%30
  print(f"{year} years, {month} months and {day} days")

year(user)
```

I am getting 11 years, 10 months and 10 days as the output. However, the question prompt also gave me some sample outputs. In their sample output the output for 4330 was 11 years, 10 months and 15 days. Why are we getting different outputs? My code is flawless. I am getting what I expected to get. However, my expected output is not matching with the output given in my prompt.

Comment: are you considering leap years?

Comment: @TalhaTayyab No, please do not consider leap years. I am editing my question to include this constraint.

Comment: Clearly your code is not a flawless as you think.

Comment: `day=num%30` only works if `365` is a multiple of `30`. It isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're calculating the number of days using `day=int((((num/365-int(num/365))*12)-month)*30)`, which I can't understand logically. A very simple, readable way would be:

```py
def year(num):
    year=num//365
    month=(num%365)//30
    day=num-(year*365)-(month*30)
    print(f"{year} years, {month} months and {day} days")

year(4330) # prints 11 years, 10 months and 15 days
```

**Edit:**

`day=num%30` wouldn't work, because it doesn't factor in the fact that an year has 365 days. Consider `num = 730`, which is 2 years and 0 days. Using your formula, you'll get `day = 10`, which is wrong.

Comment: I edited my code to make it more readable. If you want, check it out!